# An application of Hahn-Banach theorem in $l_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Recently i have learned then Hahn-Banach theorem and i'm practising with exercises to learn how to use it properly.

I tried an exercise which states:

> Prove that $\exists f \in (l_{\infty})^*$ a linear functional such that $\lim \inf_{n \longrightarrow \infty}a_n \leqslant f(\{a_n\}) \leqslant 
> \lim \sup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}a_n$ for every $a_n \in l_{\infty}$

Proof:

Firstly we notice that $  \lim \sup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}a_n$ is a sublinear functional.

Then let $(C,||*|| _{\infty})$ the space of convergent sequences which is a (closed) subspace of $l_{\infty}$.

let $a_n \in C$, we define $g(\{a_n\})=\lim a_n$

From the properties of the limit we can easily see that $g$ is a linear functional.

A convergent sequence is bounded.
Now $|g(\{a_n\})|=|\lim a_n|=\lim |a_n| \leqslant \sup_n|a_n|=||a_n||_{\infty}$,thus $g \in C^*$

From Hahn-Banach theorem exists $F \in (l_{\infty})^*$ such that $F(\{a_n\}) \leqslant \lim \sup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}a_n,\forall a_n \in l_{\infty}$

Also $-F(\{a_n\})=F(\{-a_n\}) \leqslant \lim \sup_{n \longrightarrow \infty}(-a_n)=-\lim \inf_{n \longrightarrow \infty}a_n \Longrightarrow F(\{a_n\}) \geqslant \lim \inf_{n \longrightarrow \infty}a_n$

Is this proof correct or am i missing something here?

Comment: yes you have a point,i will edit it..thank you

Comment: Don't you need to look at the sublinear functional $p(a) = \lim \sup_n |a_n|$ ?

Comment: At one point you have a typo, $\sup_n \lvert an\rvert$ instead of $\lvert a_n\rvert$, and the space of convergent sequences is usually denoted  with a lower case $c$. Apart from that, nothing to object to.

Comment: @user1952009 If we looked at $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C})$ we'd need an absolute value. For $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$, $\limsup a_n$ works fine.

Comment: yes the exercise  asks about $l_{\infty}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$